# Вызов несуществующего метода при помощи reinterpret_cast

Tags: c++

Написал такой код:

```
#include <iostream>

struct base
{
    void foo()
    {
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};

struct derived : base {};

struct other {};

int main()
{
    other o;

    base &bref = reinterpret_cast<base&>(o);
    bref.foo();
}
```

В нем создается объект типа other, у которого нет метода foo. Потом ссылка на этот объект приводится к типу `base&` (в классе `base` уже есть метод foo), и метод foo вызывается.

Почему вызов метода успешен, если `foo` вызывается у объекта, в котором нет метода `foo`?

https://ideone.com/Iafc9U

Comment: Undefined behavior не означает, что программа _обязана_ упасть. Оно означает, что программа имеет право делать что угодно.

Comment: Как вам уже сказали, как только в коде появляется UB, компилятор вам больше ничего не должен. Полюбуйтесь [вот на это](https://habrahabr.ru/company/infopulse/blog/338812/)

Answer (score 3):

Потому что он невиртуальный. И не использует никаких полей класса. Так что выполняется просто вызов кода, которому передан `this`, но который в самом вызове не нужен.

А вот сделайте его виртуальным, или хотя бы обратитесь в методе к каким-то полям...

Вот, типа https://ideone.com/AwJRRu:

```
struct base
{
    int * i = new int;
    void foo()
    {
        *i = 5;
        std::cout << "foo" << std::endl;
    }
};
```

Comment: Ну это в контексте конкретного компилятора.

Comment: @VladD Формально - да, фактически - думаю, большинство отреагируют на такой конкретный случай точно так же... VC++ и Open Watcom пропустили, о GCC ТС писал...

Comment: Достаточно умный компилятор сможет увидеть UB и выкинуть весь метод. UB очевидно, т. к. типы внутри метода известны статически. Я удивлён, что clang не догадался.

Comment: Хотя, о чём-то clang таки догадывается. Смотрите, как он выкинул 1000 в коде: https://godbolt.org/g/8m3rw1

Comment: @VladD Обманем :) - допишите `base b; b.foo();`, и код оказывается несколько иным.

Comment: Тем не менее, это ещё раз говорит о том, что UB есть UB. И что код интерпретируется далеко не «наивно», построчно, как написано.

Comment: @VladD Конечно, UB. Уж с этим-то никто не спорит :)

Comment: Я собственно о том, что предсказать, какой ассемблерный код сотворит компилятор из того или иного UB не так-то уж и просто.

Comment: @VladD Особенно при добавлении второго UB - например, использовании неинициализированной переменной :)

Comment: Ага, вот совсем простой вариант: https://godbolt.org/g/ySQtci. Тут 1000, а так же смещение переменных i, j, k тоже игнорируется.